# Laravel - Roles and permissions with multiple conditions

Tags: laravel, authorization, roles

I'm building app to manage multi-level company employees.

So, therefore, my app is structured in the following way:

**Company** has many divisions.

**Division** has many sub-divisions.

**Sub-division** has many employees.

What I'm wondering is how do set up roles and permissions in smoothest manner, considering few requirements:

**Super-admin** - can do whatever he likes.

**Manager** - can manage ONLY one (his) division and all of the sub-divisions and employees that belongs to his division.

**Coordinator** - can manage one or more divisions with each sub-division that belongs to these divisions and all of the employees.

**Group leader** - can manage one or more subdivisions from all over the place.

One way that I'm thinking is to add few extra columns to user model, something like: division_id, subdivision_id, is_super_admin, but that fails given the fact that one user can have permissions for more than one division, subdivision etc.

Building permission for each and every division/subdivision isn't good, as there should be a lot of divisions/subdivisions.

How do I even get started with this, as I'm stuck for quite some time now.

Note: Every account should have all CRUD permissions allowed, but only for his division/subdivision/employees that he owns.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can do it with Middlewares.

Answer (score 0):

Trying using spatie on laravel

https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/introduction

You can make permission, for specific role